# Query is very very slow for processing 200000 plus records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, azure-sql-database

I have 200,000 rows in `Patient` & `Person` table, and the query shown takes 30 secs to execute.

I have defined the primary key (and clustered index) in the `Person` table on `PersonId` and on `PatientId` in the `Patient` table. What else can I do here to improve performance of my procedure?

New to database development side. I know only basic SQL. Also not sure SQL Server can handle 200,000 rows quickly.

Whole dynamic Procedure you can see at https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/Performance

Anyone faced handling huge rows like this? How do I improve performance here?

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @unitRows bigint,
        @unitPages int,
        @TenantId int,
        @unitItems int,
        @page int   
SET @TenantId = 1
SET @unitItems = 20
SET @page = 1

DECLARE @PatientSearch TABLE(
    [PatientId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PatientIdentifier] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PersonNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ResFirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ResLastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AddFirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AddLastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RowNumber] [bigint] NULL
    ) 

    INSERT INTO @PatientSearch SELECT  PAT.PatientId  
     ,PAT.PatientIdentifier      
     ,PER.PersonNumber  
     ,PER.FirstName  
     ,PER.LastName  
     ,RES_PER.FirstName AS ResFirstName  
     ,RES_PER.LastName AS ResLastName  
     ,ADD_PER.FirstName AS AddFirstName  
     ,ADD_PER.LastName AS AddLastName  
     ,PER.Address  
     ,PER.City  
     ,PER.State  
     ,PER.ZipCode  
     ,PER.Country
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PAT.PatientId DESC) AS RowNumber 
  FROM  dbo.Patient AS PAT  
  INNER JOIN dbo.Person AS PER  
    ON PAT.PersonId = PER.PersonId  
  INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS RES_PER  
             ON  PAT.ResponsiblePersonId = RES_PER.PersonId  
  INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS ADD_PER  
             ON  PAT.AddedBy = ADD_PER.PersonId 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Booking AS B   
             ON PAT.PatientId = B.PatientId 

  WHERE  PAT.TenantId = @TenantId AND B.CategoryId =  @CategoryId 

  GROUP BY PAT.PatientId  
     ,PAT.PatientIdentifier      
     ,PER.PersonNumber  
     ,PER.FirstName  
     ,PER.LastName  
     ,RES_PER.FirstName 
     ,RES_PER.LastName
     ,ADD_PER.FirstName 
     ,ADD_PER.LastName
     ,PER.Address  
     ,PER.City  
     ,PER.State  
     ,PER.ZipCode  
     ,PER.Country      

  ;  

   SELECT @unitRows = @@ROWCOUNT  
     ,@unitPages = (@unitRows / @unitItems) + 1;  

   SELECT *  
   FROM @PatientSearch AS IT  
   WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @unitItems + 1 AND @unitItems * @page
```

Comment: How many rows are you inserting into your table variable? You might be better off creating an actual temp table (`#PatientSearch`). The reason is that the query optimizer will always assume that a table variable has only one row (it lacks any statistics) and thus will perform horribly bad if you insert lots of rows into a table variable

Comment: @marc_s, it actually inserts all 200000 rows for empty search :(

Comment: ***WHY*** do you need to copy all 200'000 rows into temporary table to begin with?? Can't you just define a CTE on top of your actual data, and add the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to it, and use that to select your data??

Comment: And btw: 200'000 rows isn't ***huge*** by any means.... if you're talking about 200 billion rows - then yes, that would be a *fair size* database.

Comment: @marc_s, REAL Temp table meaning `CREATE Table #PatientSearch` instead of `DECLARE @patientsearch as Table`?

Comment: Yes - because on such a temporary table, you can define indexes, if useful, and those tables have ***statistics*** - but the **BEST** way would be to avoid copying around those 200'000 rows at all!!

Comment: @marc_s, you can see my actual procedure here https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/Performance

Comment: @marc_s, replaced with temp table `#PatientSearch` and got the same result. 32 secs

Answer (score 3):

Well, unless I am missing something (like duplicate rows?) you should be able to remove the `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY PAT.PatientId  
     ,PAT.PatientIdentifier      
     ,PER.PersonNumber  
     ,PER.FirstName  
     ,PER.LastName  
     ,RES_PER.FirstName 
     ,RES_PER.LastName
     ,ADD_PER.FirstName 
     ,ADD_PER.LastName
     ,PER.Address  
     ,PER.City  
     ,PER.State  
     ,PER.ZipCode  
     ,PER.Country
```

as you are grouping by all fields in the select list, and you are partitioning by `PAT.PatientId`

Further to that, you should [create index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on the tables with the index containing columns that you join/filter on.

So for instance I would create an index on table Patient with columns (TenantId,PersonId,ResponsiblePersonId,AddedBy) with included columns (PatientId,PatientIdentifier)

Comment: I have a duplicate records because a patient has more no of bookings. I updated my query now. Its a dynamic search query. Please check

Comment: Whole procedure is at https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/Performance

Comment: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC_PatientSearch
ON dbo.Patient (TenantId,PersonId,ResponsiblePersonId,AddedBy)
INCLUDE (PatientId,PatientIdentifier)` Produces same result . Now it increase 5 more secs :(

Comment: You need to look at the execution plan, as this will give you a better understanding of what the query is doing and what indexes it is using. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-a-execution-plan-in-sql-server and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu. This should tell you more about table scans, index scans, index searches. Included columns, key lookup, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, 200,000 rows is nothing to SQL server. 
Please first remove logic redundancy, like you have primary key, why still group so many columns, and why you need to join same table (person) 3 times? 
 After removing logic redundancy, you need to create some composite index/include index at least. Get the execution plan (CTRL+M) or (CTRL+M), to see what index you missed. If you need further help, please paste your table schema with few rows of sample data.

Comment: 1 join gives me Patient First Name, 2 join for Added person First Name, 3rd Join for Responsible Doctor First Name